# Timeout expired for linq query

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I have this following query that is generating the next exception

```
 var consumption = (from c in context.ConsumptionSet
                           join pi in context.PropertiesInstanceSet on c.PropertiesInstanceID equals pi.PropertiesInstanceID
                           join ep in context.EquipmentPropertiesSet on pi.EquipmentPropertiesID equals ep.EquipmentPropertiesID
                           join e in context.EquipmentSet on ep.EquipmentID equals e.EquipmentID
                           join b in context.BoxSet on e.BoxID equals b.BoxID
                           where (b.UserID == userId && pi.ProprietesName == property && pi.Instance == 1 && e.IsGeneral == false && c.Date <= limitDate)
                           group c by e into grp
                           select new
                           {
                               eq = grp.Key,
                               //cons = grp.OrderByDescending(c => c.ConsumptionID).FirstOrDefault(),
                               cons = grp.LastOrDefault(),
                           }).ToDictionary(e => e.eq, e => e.cons);
```

Exception:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding
```

I tried to set Connect Timeout in connection string and for database context, but in vain, nothing works ..

Any idea please

Comment: If you want to increase the timeout, maybe try set the CommandTimeout on the context object.

Comment: I'd look at the generated SQL and see if it's poorly constructed

Comment: There's a lot of tables involved there - make sure all of the foreign keys are indexed, and ensure that the fields used in the `where clause` are indexed and selective.

Comment: Blindly increasing the timeout without investing the issue is a pretty bad idea.